# iOS know when touchesEnded if touches on top of certain view

Tags: ios, touch

I have to do some "snap to grid" behaviour,

I have a dragging image "sprite", but I need to "snap" this sprite to a certain button if touches go on top of that button,

so how can i know if touchesEnded is on top of a certain button,
here my code, but i dont know when touches where ended on top of butotn

```
 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{    
    UITouch *touched = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touched locationInView:touched.view];

    CGRect recta = touched.view.frame;

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(recta, self.button_1.frame)) {
        DLog(@"intersected");
    }

}
```

So this is not happening, 
can it be done?

or do i have to check the X and Y position of finishing touch against the button frame X and Y position by my self?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

touched.view is the view on which the touch started. You want to find out if the location where the touch ended is on top of a specific button. You can do this by checking if the location of the touch relative to the button is within the button's bounds.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touched = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint locationRelative = [touched locationInView:self.button_1];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.button_1.bounds, locationRelative)) {
        DLog(@"on top of button_1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CGRectIntersectsRect, which returns YES, if the two rectangles your pass to it intersect.

Comment: hi good idea thanks! i did modified my code snipet to show what im doing now, but logs as it is alwayis intersecting?, even when it really isn't , what is misisng plz?, thx!